# How to configure viewset and router based on existing viewset and router?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am a newbie in django and am trying to dabble with social website.

I have a question.

I have a Discussion Viewset

```
class DiscussionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   # general implementation
```

with urls.py

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('discussions', views.DiscussionViewSet)
app_name = 'discussion'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls))
]
```

So, this generate `/discussion/discussions/, /discussion/discussions/2`. etc..

Now, I am trying to add a similar "Comment" ViewSet on "Discussion"

I am hoping to have the functionality like

`discussion/discussions/2/comment/` -> post new comment

and `discussion/discussions/2/comment/1` -> retrieves the comment.

and so on..
I found an example here: https://github.com/DK-Nguyen/django-social-network/blob/master/discussion/urls.py
but they are using a different way to achieve this but I want to use ViewSet and router to achieve this?

Comment: I believe you're looking for this. https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers